# How to create new array from an array method?

Tags: java

I've been trying to create a small console program inspired by Among Us, however, I am stuck.

Here is my code:

```
package ImposterRandomizer;
import java.util.*;
public class ImposterRandomizer {
    
    
    public String[] imposterChoose(int y, String[] playerList) {
        double imposter1;
        double imposter2;
        double imposterNumbers[]= new double[2];
        String imposterFinal[]= {"name1","name2"};
        
        //if player count is 6 or less
        if (y>=6) {
            imposterNumbers[0] = Math.round((Math.random()*y));
        }
        
        //if player count is greater than 6, 2 imposters are required
        else {
            imposterNumbers[0] = Math.round(Math.random()*y);
            imposterNumbers[1] = Math.round(Math.random()*y); 
            
            //check if imposter numbers are the same
            while (imposterNumbers[0]==imposterNumbers[1]) {imposterNumbers[1] = Math.round(Math.random()*y);}
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
            int count = 0;
            
            if(x==imposterNumbers[0]) {
                imposterFinal[count] = playerList[x];
                count++;
            }
            if(x==imposterNumbers[1]) {
                imposterFinal[count] = playerList[x];
                count++;
            }
            return new String[] {imposterFinal[0], imposterFinal[1]};
    }
    
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declaring varaibles
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] imposterFinal = new String[2];
        
        //sysout print sequence
        System.out.println("Please enter player names separated by a comma: ");
        String nameList = input.nextLine();
        String[] playerNames = nameList.split(",");
        
        //imposter assigner
        imposterFinal[] = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames[]);
        System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Basically I'd like to input a list in one line, split the line by commas and put into a new array. I'd then like to use this array later on to do other things, like print out who the two chosen "imposters" are.

On line 53 I get a message that says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable." I am not sure if I am using the right way of calling a method to create an array, or if I'm mistaken somewhere else in the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `imposterFinal[] = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames[]);` with `imposterFinal = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames[]);` if this is only about syntax error

Comment: `//if player count is 6 or less` `if (y>=6)` should this not be `<= 6`

Comment: @SCC need to remove [] at the right-hand side too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make **imposterChoose** to be static, because you call it from a static method

```
public static String[] imposterChoose(int y, String[] playerList) {
```

Second, edit

```
imposterFinal[] = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames[]);
```

To

```
imposterFinal = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax errors can be noted in your code.

---

#### 1 When referring an array you must **not** put `[]` syntax.

> `imposterFinal[] = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames[]);`

must be changed to,

`imposterFinal = imposterChoose(playerNames.length, playerNames);`

---

#### 2 Non-static methods must not be called from static methods

> `public String[] imposterChoose(int y, String[] playerList) {\\...}`

You are calling this method from the main method, which is a static method. So you can simply make this method static too.

---

#### 3 A method must return something as defined in method definition

Please take a note at the following method.

> ```
> public String[] imposterChoose(int y, String[] playerList) {
>     
>     // ...
>
>     for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
>
>       //...
>
>       return new String[] { imposterFinal[0], imposterFinal[1] };
>     }
> }
> ```

Here, you are only returning inside the `for` loop! So, it will only return something if the for loop is ran.

i.e. If always `x < y` then this method will not enter to the for loop and will not return anything.

At least it must return a `null`.

```
public static String[] imposterChoose(int y, String[] playerList) {
    
    // ...

    for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) {

      //...

      return new String[] { imposterFinal[0], imposterFinal[1] };
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

#### 4 When creating a String[] from numbers, you must convert them to strings properly.

> ```
> imposterNumbers[0] = Math.round(Math.random() * y);
> imposterNumbers[1] = Math.round(Math.random() * y); 
>
> new String[] { imposterFinal[0], imposterFinal[1] };
> ```

Here you are directly using outputs from `Math.round()` as strings which may be a syntax error. So you can just say like,

```
new String[] { imposterFinal[0].toString(), imposterFinal[1].toString() };
```